# Authentication with AngularFire

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i am trying to do authentication with angularfire.

```
myApp.controller('UsersCtrl', ['$scope', 'angularFireAuth',function UsersCtrl($scope, 

angularFireAuth) {

var url = 'https://nikskohli.firebaseio.com/users';

angularFireAuth.initialize(url, {scope: $scope, name: "user"});

$scope.addUser = function(user) {
    console.debug("new user", user)
    users.push(user);
}

$scope.login = function() {
    console.debug("logging in")
    angularFireAuth.login("facebook");
};

$scope.logout = function() {
    angularFireAuth.logout();
};

$scope.$on("angularFireAuth:login", function(evt, user) {
  console.debug("login event", user)
});
$scope.$on("angularFireAuth:logout", function(evt) {
   console.debug("logout event", user)
});
$scope.$on("angularFireAuth:error", function(evt, err) {
    console.debug("auth error", err)
  // There was an error during authentication.
}); 
  }
]);
```

There is no error but i know i am missing some dependencies

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.firebase.com/v0/firebase.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.firebase.com/v0/firebase-auth-client.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.1.5/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src= "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angularFire/0.5.0/angularfire.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using an old version of firebase.

Use these instead:

```
 <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/1.0.15/firebase.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/0.7.1/angularfire.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/simple-login/1.5.0/firebase-simple-login.js"></script>
```

And change `angularFireAuth` for `$firebaseSimpleLogin`. Also, change your AngularJS:

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.min.js"></script>
```

You could check the detailed explanation [here](https://www.firebase.com/docs/angular/reference.html).

Comment: Yes, i tried to change it with the following dependency but still it doesn't work.

Comment: It should work now, I update the answer with the solution. Apparently you're using an old version of Firebase and AngularJs.